# Being Galois is not transitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F\subseteq B\subseteq E$ be fields. I want to prove that if $E/B$ and $B/F$ are Galois, then $E/F$ need not be Galois. Hint: $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$.

Is it a proper hint? I don't understand something. I believe that $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q})=\{1\}$, because if $\sigma :\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\to\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is an automorphism that fixes every element of $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\sigma(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$ because it must be a root of $x^2-2$. Hence $\sigma$ is the identity.

Therefore the fixed field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})^{\{1\}}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\neq\mathbb{Q}$. Hence $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ is not Galois.

Am I wrong?

Comment: note that $-\sqrt{2}$ is also a root of $x^2-2$, so $\sigma(\sqrt{2}) = -\sqrt{2}$ is possible.